# Can't get rid of 'Declarations From Extensions cannot be overridden yet'

Tags: ios, swift

I can't get rid of this error. Based on the screenshot below, the property `borderColor` of the library called **Material** is conflicting with the property of the **VKCheckbox** library.

**VKCheckbox's borderColor**

```
/**
 Set checkbox border color
 */
var borderColor: UIColor!
{
    didSet
    {
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
}
```

**Material+UIView.swift**

```
extension UIView {
    /// A property that accesses the layer.borderColor property.
    open var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            guard let v = layer.borderColor else {
                return nil
            }
            return UIColor(cgColor: v)
        }
        set(value) {
            layer.borderColor = value?.cgColor
        }
    }
...
}
```

So the question is, how do I solve this? No idea at all. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You need to rename one of the two `borderColor` properties.

Comment: Thanks! There's no other way? :/